# Catching IOException in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, ioexception, assertion

I would like to ask for help on how am I be able to catch IOException on my JUnit testing just to test if my code will throw the right exception once error occured.

Here is my main code:

```
public void LogHostStream(String v_strText) {
    
    Date dtToday = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(dtToday);
    
    SimpleDateFormat FILE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String filedate = FILE_DATE_FORMAT.format(dtToday);
    
    IConfiguration cfgHandler = ConfigurationFactory.getConfigHandle();
    String logFileName = cfgHandler.GetXMLValue("config.xml", "/config/log/host_logs");
    
    String outText = String.format("%s \n %s \n", date, v_strText);
    String fileName = logFileName + "_" + filedate + ".txt";

    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);) {
        bw.write(outText);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here is my JUnit:

```
 @Test(expected = IOException.class)
public void testLogHostStreamThrowsIOException() throws IOException {
    logger.LogHostStream("");
    String logFileName = cfgHandler.GetXMLValue("ocomw_config.xml", "/config/log/host_logs");
    FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(logFileName, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
           
    Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> new BufferedWriter(bw));    
}
```

I think I have to create a wrong path on my JUnit test to throw that exception, but I was not able to get the result I want.  I appreciate any help for this. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you're mixing two separate styles of expecting an exception, using `expected = ` _and also_ using `assertThrows`. Use only one or the other (and make sure that you aren't mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit 5).

Answer (score 0):

`FileWriter` will throw an exception when it cannot create or open the file for writing. One way to make this happen is making sure the directory the file is supposed to be in does not exist. This test succeeds:

```
@Test
void testThrows() throws IOException {
    assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> new FileWriter("/no/such/place"));
}
```

Creating a `BufferedWriter` will never throw an `IOException`, which means this assertion will always fail:

```
assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> new BufferedWriter(bw));
```

You shouldn't write tests for `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter` though: they are well tested standard library classes and you can trust that they work as specified.

Comment: Hi, but I was not still able to catch IOException in my JUnit.  I changed it according to your suggestion. I know it had to a wrong path, but I just can't figure out how to do this in my test. Thanks anyways for the answer.

`@Test
    public void testLogHostStreamThrowsIOException() throws IOException {
        Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> new FileWriter("/no/such/place", true));
        logger.LogHostStream("");
       
    }`

Comment: the catch block on my main code is not still covered by JUnit.

Comment: Your "main code" gets the path of the file from a method call to `cfgHandler.GetXMLValue`. You need to make that method return an incorrect path. Do you have a method like `cfgHandler.SetXMLValue` or some other way to inject custom configuration values that are used only for the test?

Answer (score 0):

It is meaningless to call `Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> new BufferedWriter(bw));` to test standard library. In fact you should call `Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> logger.LogHostStream("logText"));` to test your own method.

The reason you can't get the exception is that `() -> new BufferedWriter(bw));` will never throw any exception. The place where exception is thrown is `FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(logFileName, true);`

If you want to test your method to checkout whether it throws the excpeted exception, you should remove your try-catch block like this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(outText);
```

Because once you catch your exception, you can't check the exception with `Assertions.assertThrows`

After that you should change the value of `/config/log/host_logs` in `ocomw_config.xml`  to a invalid path value. Then call `Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, () -> logger.LogHostStream("someLogText"));`, and you will see the excepted exception.